# jQuery selector NOT

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do i select everything BUT the element with an id?

```
<div id="test">
<p id="test"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

I want to be able to select the second and third

Comment: You can't have 2 elements with the same id!

Comment: @nik: Yes you can(Obama). It's just not valid and definitly not recommendable.

Comment: How will jQuery react to having multiple elements with the same ID? :)

Comment: @njk: it will only query/select the first occurence: http://www.jsfiddle.net/v4wkv/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have 2 elements with the id "test" but if the code was as follows:

```
<div id="test">
<p id="test2"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

then you could use

```
$("#test p").not("#test2")
```

or

```
$("#test p:not(#test2)")
```

to select just the other two paragraphs.

See http://api.jquery.com/not/ for the documentation for the not() method (first option) or http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ for the :not() selector (second option).

Note: this won't select "everything" but rather the second and third paragraph elements. I assume that's what you meant :)

Comment: You're welcome! Can you 'accept' the answer by clicking on the checkmark, if this met your needs?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [has-attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
$(":not([id])")
```

A few notes though, you currently have 2 elements with the same ID, this is invalid because IDs should be unique.  Also you shouldn't use the selector *exactly* as I have it above, it should be within something, for example `$("#test :not([id])")` to narrow it down ... it's *very* expensive otherwise.

Comment: I would also note it selects everything *inside* `<p id="test"></p>`, which isn't always welcomed.

Comment: @Kobi - I don't follow you there...it doesn't select everything, it wouldn't select the first element, only the second and third like he asked for...

Comment: ohwoh, I wrote that when the description was not there, I'll delete it

Comment: If you have `<p id="test"><strong>in the P</strong></p>`, the `<strong>` element gets selected too. It's good for the posted code, of course. Isn't too important, really :) (actually, I suppose I only mentioned it because I had a similar bug once, with bubbling events)