# animate back to default if visitor clicks anyplace else on the webpage besides the div

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

```
$("#image").click(function(){
        $("#image-container").animate({"width": "350px"}, 500);
    });
```

How do I make the #image-container animate back to its original size when a visitor clicks anyplace else, but just not the #image?

I could do it this way, with the original size animate back thing.

```
$("#image").click(function(){
        $("#image-container").animate({"width": "200px"}, 500);
    });
```

But is there a better way and also, how to I make the div animate when visitor clicks elsewhere?

Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is working on [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/ywTKL/1)

```
$(document).click(function(){
        $("#image-container").animate({"width": "200px"}, 500);
 });
$("#image").click(function(){
        $("#image-container").animate({"width": "350px"}, 500);
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Why did you put return false?

Comment: Return false will prevent further propagation of event . so it will not bubble to document.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
.not( selector )Returns: jQuery
Description: Remove elements from the set of matched elements.
```

or this answer: [jQuery selector NOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310134/jquery-selector-not)

//apply the selector to all visible items

```
$(document).find('*').not("#image").is(':visible').click(function(){
        $("#image-container").animate({"width": "200px"}, 500);
 });
```

Comment: `.not()` filters out the current collection of elements.. which you have only have the document

Comment: @wirey please explain the -1

Comment: document will not have the id=image so it will filter nothing out

Comment: `$('.class').not('#certainid')` will filter out the element with `class=class` and `id=certainid` out of the `$('.class')` collection of elements.. you currently selected the docuement.. and saying all documents - but not the document with id=image

Comment: corrected the jquery, now all children of current document except the one with specific id  will have the click function.

Comment: @wirey edited my post, it was easier to use the edit button :)